# BuildContext for a class

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter,
I created a class for a reusable Card, but I don't know how can build a context here for my raisedButton. Please Help !

[image]

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:kebhips/Pages/TimeTablePage1.dart';

   class ProgrammesDetails{
     final String id;
     final String name;
     final String time;
     final String description;
     final String image;
     final String picture;
     final RaisedButton raisedButton;

      ProgrammesDetails({this.id, this.name, this.time,
          this.description, this.image, this.picture, this.raisedButton});
        }


         List<ProgrammesDetails> programmesDetails = [
           ProgrammesDetails(
          id: "1",
          name: "B T S",
  time: "Deux ans",
  description: "Le BTS (Brevet de Technicien Supérieur), est un diplôme national de l'enseignement supérieur qui se prépare en deux ans apès le baccalauréat et qui ouvre la voie à plus de 50 spécialités dans différents secteurs. Le BTS est pensé pour favoriser une orientation professionnelle rapide sans fermer la porte à la poursuite des études. Sa particularité réside dans la nature professionnalisante de son contenu pédagoque et son enseignement pratique porté par de nombreuses semaines de stage en entreprise. Le BTS conduit à l'btention d'un diplôme de niveau bac+2 reconnu par l'Etat. Sa validation ouvre naturellement les portes au marché de l'emploi.",
  image: "assets/img/mars.png",
  picture: "https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/thumbnails/image/pia21723-16.jpg",
  raisedButton: RaisedButton(
      onPressed: (){
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => TimeTablePage()));
      })
           ),
```

https://github.com/rslimm/kelden.git

Comment: I suggest you share code instead of screenshots so in case of required we could reproduce the issue easily.

Comment: @MisirJafarov, https://github.com/rslimm/kelden.git

Answer (score 1):

You are doing something wrong, but to access context from any method you could use StatefulWidget instead of StatelessWidget.

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  ...
}
```

You can read more about using `StatefulWidget` from [flutter docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/interactive).
Also, check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AqCMFXEmf3w).

Answer (score 0):

Context is captured from 
Widget build(BuildContext context)

Need to implement whether it’s Stateless or Stateful widget

For reference 
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BuildContext-class.html

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/interactive